# Vala compiler cannot find gee.h

Tags: compiling, vala

[I followed the GNOME guid to setup Vala on Ubuntu.](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaOnLinux) and try the [first GEE sample](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GeeSamples).

```
$ valac --pkg gee-0.8 gee-list.vala 
gee-list.vala.c:8:10: fatal error: gee.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gee.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I have all dev packages are installed and the header is a `/usr/include/gee-0.8/gee.h`. Is there something else I have to setup?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the Pantheon desktop.

1. Update more info about my environment:

```
~$ echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/7
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7
 /usr/include/c++/7/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

```
$ echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c - -fsyntax-only
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Comment: I read somewhere you need build essentials installed: `apt list | grep build-ess` to check.

Comment: Note for above: `apt list | grep ^build-ess` will give a single line without other packages.

Comment: `build-essential` and `libgee-0.8.dev` are both already installed

Comment: What is the output of `echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only` and `echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c - -fsyntax-only`?

Comment: @Kulfy I added more infos. Should there be somethinbgs vala related?

Comment: Regarding to https://github.com/rastersoft/autovala/issues/53 this is more a generic issue, than ubuntu related. Three keywords seems to be important 'clean install directory', `autovala update` and '`cmake ..` again'

Comment: @Lupus I will investigate as I just installed the packages and expected it to *just work*

Answer (score 1):

Some general compiling tips about missing header files:

- [Compiler cannot find header file, do I add the directory to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174562/compiler-cannot-find-header-file-do-i-add-the-directory-to-path)

> Adding the appropriate directory to your include path is exactly what
>   you're supposed to do in this case, only you're supposed to do it by
>   pkg-config. Accessing the files directly using full pathnames is
>   unsupported.
>
> Add something like this to your Makefile:
>
> ```
> CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` 
>  LIBS += `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
> ```
>
> This will automatically add the correct compiler and linker options
>   for the current system.

From [mail archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/vala-list@gnome.org/msg11975.html) there are some tips that might be useful:

> Re: [Vala] Package `Gee-0.8' not found
>
> Ralf Ganswindt Fri, 26 Jan 2018 22:08:52 -0800
>
> Thank you, that was the missing info. I figured out the proper name
>   for the ubuntu repository to get the -dev package and voila the .gir
>   file appeared where it should. I looked through the vala directories
>   and found it under /usr/share/vala/vapi/, but valac still couldn't
>   find it until I copied the file to /usr/share/vala-0.36/vapi/. I don't
>   know if this is unique to Ubuntu, but I figure this might be useful to
>   someone.

Thanks again,

Ralf

Ralf Ganswindt
ralfganswi...@gmail.com

On Thu, Jan 25, 2018 at 12:03 PM, Al Thomas  wrote:

>

> > On Thursday, 25 January 2018, 16:41:31 GMT, Ralf Ganswindt <
> >     ralfganswi...@gmail.com> wrote:
> >
> > I'm experimenting with Vala and so far I like how it works. However, I
> >     tried to compile a basic gee example from the sample programs and I get
> >     the
> >     following:
> >
> > $ valac --pkg Gee-0.8 list.vala
> >     error: Package `Gee-0.8' not found in specified Vala API directories or
>
> It should be --pkg gee-0.8 It is case sensitive!
>
> You also need the development files installed. For Ubuntu that would be
>   something like
>   apt install libgee-dev
>
> > GIR files:
> >     You want to avoid GIR files to start with. They are GObject Introspection
> >     Repository (GIR)
> >     files that contain enough information about a C library's interface to
> >     generate bindings for
> >     various languages, including Vala. The Vala tool vapigen can then be used
> >     to generate a
> >     Vala Application Programming Interface (VAPI) file from the GIR. valac can
> >     do this automatically
> >     if a VAPI is not found.
>
> By using the capitalized version, --pkg Gee-0.8, valac tried to generate
>   the VAPI for you by
>   searching for the relevant GIR. It looks like that wasn't found either,
>   probably because you
>   don't have the development files installed. If you look at the files in
>   the dev package you
>   should see the difference in filenames.
>
> When starting out you want to focus on using VAPI files for interfacing
>   with libraries.
>
> All the best,
>
> Al
>
> ---

vala-list mailing list
vala-list@gnome.org
https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/vala-list

Additionally I read somewhere that `build-essentials` should be installed as well.

```
sudo apt install build-essentials
```

Comment: The package is `libgee-0.8-dev` to be precise. Don't think this answer applies to op's case.

Comment: @JacobVlijm is right. Both packages are already installed. I can find the libgee header, so it is installed. Some include path or env var is borked... :-/